# Could not find this method in Spring API

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I couldn’t find the ‘`using`’ method given below in the API.

```
public class QuerydslBindings
extends Object
```

QuerydslBindings allows definition of path specific SingleValueBinding.

```
 new QuerydslBindings() {
   {
     bind(QUser.user.address.city).using((path, value) -> path.like(value.toString()));
     bind(String.class).using((path, value) -> path.like(value.toString()));
   }
 }
```

Comment: Looks like a documentation issue, as the definition is not there yet. The only branch which has this documentation is https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/blob/DATACMNS-293/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/querydsl/binding/QuerydslBindings.java

Comment: I felt the same but wanted to check if anyone is familiar. Thank You